# Xcode5: Move child tabBarController to the top

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, uitabbarcontroller

This question has been asked many times before but since it has been a while since, maybe things have improved for xCode5 and iOS7. I don't know so I am asking it again:

I have a Tab Bar Controller whose tabs I want to appear on top as opposed to at the bottom. Is there a way to do this with the present iOS IDE tools? (i.e. Xcode5, iOS7, etc.)

Comment: No. In order to do that you should use custom view controller.

Comment: That's the default way, unless you hide the Tab Bar Controller and make a custom one. :)